# what is difference betwen string and tuple?

Tags: python, string, tuples

Can anyone explain what is difference between string and tuple

```
a="string"
b=("s","t","r","i","n","g")
```

both are immutable.

Comment: Basically everything? Eg `print(a)` and `print(b)` are different, you can't `.split`, `.join`, `.trim` etc on a tuple.

Comment: Everything except the fact that both are immutable.

Comment: Actually you should ask "what is the same between string and tuple"

Comment: Try calling string methods on your tuple.

Comment: Note that `b` is a tuple _of_ strings, so the better question might be "What is the difference between `"string"` and `(,)`"

Answer (score 2):

They're different types.

```
"str" in a  # True
("s", "t", "r") in b  # False
```

Which means they have different methods, different use cases, different meanings, different implementations, etc. etc. etc....  Consider:

```
datapoint_tuple = (datetime.datetime.now(), 42)
datapoint_str = ...???
```

Essentially the only thing they have in common is their immutability.

Comment: An interesting point that's relevant to this: in some languages (though not Python) a valid question would be "What's the difference between a string and a _list_." Many languages implement strings as a naive list of `Char` values.

Answer (score 1):

**Strings** are immutable in python which means it cannot be changed once created, if you want to update it then a new string is to be created for example.

```
s="Abcdef"
c=s+'112'
print s,c
```

you can extract value using index, find values but cannot modify it

To access substrings, use the square brackets for slicing along with the index or indices to obtain your substring

**Tuple** they are immutable like strings and sequence like lists.They are used to store data just like list, just like string you cannot update or edit the tuple to change it you have to create a new one just like strings.Tuples can be created using parenthesis () and data is inserted using comas.

```
t1=(1,2,3,'hi')
print type(t1)
print t1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A **string** is a sequence of unicode characters with quotation marks on either side of the sequence.

Example: `mystring = "this is a string"`

A **tuple** is an ordered sequence of objects or characters separated by commas with parentheses on either side of the sequence.

Example: `mytuple = (7, "u", "p", 1, "e')`

They are, however, similar in the fact that they are both immutable

Comment: tuples certainly don't have to be characters -- they contain arbitrary heterogeneous python values (see my use of a `datetime.DateTime` in my answer). Also perhaps worth pointing out that strings are only unicode (by default) in Python3, though I may be stretching the word "Worth" there :)

Comment: Just to split the hair further: characters _are_ objects, so saying "objects or characters" is redundant. Really, though, it's fine :)

Comment: @AdamSmith lol you sound like me nitpicking everything :).  tbh you deserve the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

```
t1 = (1,2,3,4)
t2 =(1,2,3,4)
print( t1 is t2)
```

**Output:** True

This means they refer to the same object and string does the same thing. But tuples comes into play when few data need to stay together. For example: file name, it's size and type. Even when you return multiple values they are returned as a tuple.

```
def convert_seconds(seconds):
 hours = seconds//3600
 minutes = (seconds - hours*3600)//60
 remaining_seconds = seconds- hours*3600 - minutes*60
 return hours,minutes,remaining_seconds 
result = convert_seconds(5000)
print(type(result))
```

**output:** <class 'tuple'>

Once you know why using it, it will clear your confusion.

Answer (score 0):

String are *immutable* and tuples are also *immutable* but it's **member objects** may be mutable

Comment: Member objects: objects separated by commas and enclosed in parentheses() .

Comment: As this is just one difference between strings and tuples you should add more information to your answer. It doesn't add to existing answers either since they've also made your point.

Answer (score -1):

tuple use a trailing comma:

```
tuple_a = 'a',
print(type(tuple_a)) # <class 'tuple'>
```

string don't use:

```
string_a = 'a'
print(type(string_a)) # <class 'str'>
```

but string and tuple has some same characteristics。
eg:
1、indexing and slicing

```
string_same = 'string'
tuple_same = ('s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g')
print(string_same[0], tuple_same[0]) # s s
print(string_same[:-1], tuple_same[:-1]) # strin ('s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n')
```

2、Immutability
means string and tuple not suport item assigment

```
string_same[0] = 'python_'
tuple_same[0] = 'python_'
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

you could find all of the diffrent from the Doc.
including other tyeps build-in types.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tuple#tuple